# Run Jupyter notebook in an anaconda environment on Windows 10

Tags: windows, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I recently create a anaconda env by:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env python=3.6
conda activate tensorflow_env
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Then I install jupyter notebook in the tensorflow_env,

```
conda install jupyter
```

Then I run it with

```
jupyter notebook
```

I got a blank website:
[image]
Anyone knows what's going on here? I use windows 10. And the jupyter notebook works fine if I don't run it with in the tensorflow_env environment. But if I don't run the jupyter in that environment, I can't **import tensorflow**.

Comment: You may need to install another package: `conda install nb_conda_kernels`.

Comment: After installing the package and restarting the laptop, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Now I post my comment as an answer. The best way to thank someone that provided you a useful answer is clicking a vote-up and/or the accept button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to install additional package:

```
conda install nb_conda_kernels
```

and restart the Jupyter notebook server again.