# Run Jupyter from an environment in Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, windows-10

I have just started working with jupyter, and I am unable to run jupyter on Windows 10 from the terminal that gets shipped with Anaconda. I am sorry if this question is basic. I research a bunch of threads on SO [Run Jupyter notebook in an anaconda environment on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173721/run-jupyter-notebook-in-an-anaconda-environment-on-windows-10) [Run Jupyter notebook out of Jupyter environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296346/run-jupyter-notebook-out-of-jupyter-environment), but I couldn't find any help. Please see below.

[image: Win Start Screen]

Here's the screenprint of the error: please note that I want to use `tf` environment that has tensorflow package installed.

[image]

Alternatively, if I run jupyter through:

```
Anaconda Navigator > Environments > tf > Open Terminal
```

Here's what I get. All my tensorflow scripts run beautifully.

[image]

**Question:**

While I understand that I have a workaround to open jupyter, but going through Navigator is very painful. Is there anyway to run `jupyter notebook` directly? I think there is no issue with my environment because `tf` loads from navigator.

Can someone please help me?

---

From windows start > here's the screen for environment list:
[image]

Here's conda info:

```
(base) C:\Users\USER>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\USER\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\USER\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.7.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USER\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Here's conda info for `ts`:

```
(base) C:\Users\USER>conda activate tf

(tf) C:\Users\USER>conda info

     active environment : tf
    active env location : C:\Anaconda3\envs\tf
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\USER\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\USER\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.7.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USER\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. One needs to install `jupyter` metapackage. Then the problem is solved. I am not too sure why. If someone can explain why this is happening, it will be great.